# Shell command not working as expected

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell command that will append a   ',' at the end of each line and will output the result to a new file.
I have written the following code-

```
 sed -e 's/$/,/g' -e '$ s/,$//' name.txt > output
```

The above code executes and places the comma operator in  a new line, i.e. if the input file is

```
aabbcc
ddeeff
```

the output shown is-

```
aabbcc
,
ddeeff
```

instead of

```
aabbcc,
ddeeff
```

What changes should I make to get the expected output ? I also tried

```
awk '{print $0","}' name.txt > output
```

but it displays the output file exactly as above.

Comment: Does your input file have DOS line endings?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes I think so. I tried to convert it to GNU format using  `     sed -i 's/\r$//' emails.txt` and then executed the command, it works fine. Can you tell me how to accomplish this task using single shell command ?

Comment: Add that bit of sed to your existing sed command.

Comment: easy to chain multiple substitutions together in `sed`. i.e. `sed 's/\r$//;s/$/,/g;$ s/,$//' name.txt > output` The `-e` is not normally needed (in real life). There are cases where it will help, but I don't know why it's so popular. (One of lifes' little mysteries ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Maybe we are sadly not as clever as Mr Shelter ;-) Good luck ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell : clever? just lazy ; -) Good luck to all!